# Relation between the output density matrix and the annihilation operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, density-operator

The annihilation opertors $\{\hat{a_R}^{(m)}\}_{m=1}^{M}$ of the modes obey the relation
\begin{align}
\label{annihilation}
\hat{a_R}_R^{m}
&= \sqrt{\eta_h} e^{i \phi} \hat{a_S}^{(m)} + \sqrt{1- \eta_h}  \hat{a_B}^{(m)}. 
\tag{1}
\end{align}
The initial state is
\begin{align}
\vert \Psi \rangle_{IS}
&= \sum_n \sqrt{p_n} \vert \chi_n \rangle_I \vert n \rangle_S.
\tag{2}
\end{align}
Then by the Schrodinger picture, how to derive the output density operators
\begin{align}
\rho_h 
&= [id_I \otimes(u_{\phi} \circ\mathbb{L}_{\eta_h, N_B^{h}})^{\otimes M}](\vert \Psi \rangle_{IS} \langle \Psi \vert_{IS}).
\tag{3}
\end{align}
using (\ref{annihilation})?

This question is related to equation (1),(3), and (4) in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.12252)